# how to make nemiver hit breakpoints?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gcc

how to make nemiver hit breakpoints and show all var values?

I tried the gcc g++ -O0 (o zero, unoptimized) compiler flag, that should grant no src code would be shrunk, but nemiver still misses like 33% of the breakpoints i set...

manytimes nemiver stops after the breakpoint i set too. Other times it just completely misses my src class and jumps to some basic class like string.

and to worsen things, i cant see values inside vectors, and other vars just show "optimized oitput" instead of the value, what is totally useless, any workaround to them?

it seems that macro expansions also mess the breakpoint position. And i read we could generate a precode that have all macros expanded right? Wonder if it could help?

anyother lightweight debugger that dont need to configure anything and just auto finds all sources like nemiver does? I dont want to spend days configuring eclipse or visualcode to work in linux gcc. With nemiver you just run the app and it takes care of showing all src code you need, but missing breakpoints and not showing all var values is really annoying..

ps.: i am trying to debug arx libertatis in linux.

Comment: Since your question doesn't mention it, are you actually using the `-g` flag to generate debug symbols?

Comment: I use a cmakelists option to set unoptimized code in arx libertatis, but i didnt know about -g. As soon i can turn on my pc i will look for it, looks like a good probable hint!

Comment: Random open source tool (like debugger named nemiver) does not work like you expect. There are two ways, 1) put up defect report to their issue management or 2) fix it yourself and put up pull request to their repo. What you do 3) write suggestion request to stackoverflow for other tools and/or tutorials is wrong.

Comment: I usually pass `-ggdb -O0 -fno-omit-frame_pointer`. Does that help?

Comment: @sehe it worked! I think -g -O0 only wasant working well, but your line made a difference. I can see values in vectors and all breakpoints seem to be working! I saw a line where nemiver expected another thing from gdb, i will search about that if i still face some problem, thx!

Comment: @ÖöTiib the core of my question wasnt the suggestion request. That was also a complaint on how can a top enterprise tool be less intuitive to use than a random open source tool? A small group of ppl seems to be doing a better work than a corporation in a few aspects, so the corporation should learn something from them. But your scary warning is good, next time i will hide my brilliant suggestions in a spoiler section as they can be considered out of the question scope even if they are coherent, thx :)

Comment: That is often so. Open source we make with love towards our work and pride of master. Minimum viable looks brief, clean and intuitive. Corporate stuff is full of whatever bloat, vapour and deception sales department did order. More sells better despite it is tedious to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when not optimizing, compilers can omit frame-pointers for simple functions making it so that debuggers cannot distinguish the function entry point on the stack.

I use this combination on my debugging:

```
-ggdb -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer
```

and it seems to be able to allow me to step through reasonably completely (not using nemiver, but other gdb-based debuggers).